# PROCESS macro in SPSS - Analysis for multiple IV?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, interaction

I have a moderated mediation model with 4 IVs, 1 mediator, 1 moderator, and 1 DV. I can't find the right model in the templates provided by Andrew Hayes for his SPSS PROCESS macro. Can I carry out one analysis per each IV I have in my model? i.e. four different analyses? Or is there another way to test my  model? Thank you!

Comment: You might need to consult Hayes' book to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I could finally find the answer in the Hayes' book (pp. 196-197):

As discussed in section 6.2, PROCESS can estimate a mediation model with statistical controls as in Figure 6.3, so it follows that it can also estimate a model with multiple X variables. However, in order to estimate the direct and indirect effects of all k X variables in Figure 6.5, PROCESS must be executed k times, each time putting one Xi in the model as X and the remaining k − 1 X variables as covariates. Each time PROCESS is run, the direct and indirect effects of the variable listed as X will be generated. Repeating k − 1 times generates the indirect effects for all k X variables. Mathematically, all resulting paths, direct, and indirect effects will be the same as if they had all been estimated simultaneously (as in a structural equation modeling program). [...] 
In the preceding code, the random number generator is seeded with a common (and arbitrary) seed using the seed= option so that at each run, the bootstrap confidence intervals will be based on the same set of 10,000 resamples from the data. It makes no difference what seed is used—pick it randomly if you choose as I did in the code above—so long as it is a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

What if one can develop on function of IV using $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) =b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_2+b_4x_4$ obtained from previous multiple regression model from SPSS. This can be computer using data transformation. I believe the function obtain will be the weighted result of X which is one IV then you can use Hayes processor to obtain moderate mediation of 1IV,1 mediator and 1 moderator. I may not have supporting evidence but open to discussion.